# How to use GLEW with MinGW

Tags: c++, c, opengl, mingw, glew

I was trying to use glew32.lib file to link in my project, than I compile Glew source by myself to get glew.a file. Now, I have these link errors in my project:

```
g++ -o Chapter10(OpenCLTest).exe src\Chapter10(OpenCLTest).o -lopengl32 -lglew -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopencl
src\Chapter10(OpenCLTest).o:Chapter10(OpenCLTest).cpp:(.text+0x167): undefined reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'
src\Chapter10(OpenCLTest).o:Chapter10(OpenCLTest).cpp:(.text+0x39a): undefined reference to `_imp__glewInit'
src\Chapter10(OpenCLTest).o:Chapter10(OpenCLTest).cpp:(.text+0x3a7): undefined reference to `_imp__glewIsSupported'
src\Chapter10(OpenCLTest).o:Chapter10(OpenCLTest).cpp:(.text+0x48a): undefined reference to `_imp____glewGenBuffers'
src\Chapter10(OpenCLTest).o:Chapter10(OpenCLTest).cpp:(.text+0x495): undefined reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'
src\Chapter10(OpenCLTest).o:Chapter10(OpenCLTest).cpp:(.text+0x4dd): undefined reference to `_imp____glewBufferData'
src\Chapter10(OpenCLTest).o:Chapter10(OpenCLTest).cpp:(.text+0x50b): undefined reference to `_imp____glewGetBufferParameteriv'
src\Chapter10(OpenCLTest).o:Chapter10(OpenCLTest).cpp:(.text+0x1d67): undefined reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'
src\Chapter10(OpenCLTest).o:Chapter10(OpenCLTest).cpp:(.text+0x1d7f): undefined reference to `_imp____glewDeleteBuffers'
src\Chapter10(OpenCLTest).o:Chapter10(OpenCLTest).cpp:(.text+0x1d95): undefined reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'
src\Chapter10(OpenCLTest).o:Chapter10(OpenCLTest).cpp:(.text+0x1dad): undefined reference to `_imp____glewDeleteBuffers'
src\Chapter10(OpenCLTest).o:Chapter10(OpenCLTest).cpp:(.text+0x2078): undefined reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It is good to solve this problem but by the way I want to ask are there any other opengl implementaions of gl extentions?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to find libraries compiled with g++ or build them yourself.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Which OS? I think it is just a matter to specify to the compiler where to find the lib file (or .so depending on the system we are talking about). I use GLEW since more than one year on my Linux Box and everything is very straight forward. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [GLee](http://elf-stone.com/glee.php) which essentially does the same thing as GLEW.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid you can't use glew.lib with g++ (because .lib is a proprietary Microsoft format). These errors you get are missing function entry points, meaning that you didn't compile GLEW correctly (the required functions are not exported in your .so - need to know more details in order to be able to solve this issue).

As for the other part of the question, you can try [GLEH](http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xpolok00/proj_gleh.htm). It is still in the development phase and may need some tweaking to work for you, but we've been using it quite successfuly in linux so it shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 2):

(I know this is a bit late, but I figured it might solve someone else's problem, so) I had a very similar problem compiling a program that linked to GLEW dynamically. It turns out that I had overlooked the `libglew32.dll.a` file - that also needed to be present (in addition to `libglew32.a` and `glew32.dll` that I had previously copied to my project folder.)

Comment: I had same issue just now, which solved it. I suspected it to be solution but was not eager of whole recompilation process. Anyway, download source, compile with mingw (4.8) make, and copy it to same as .exe did the trick - just for the future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Strange nobody has said anything about this.  By default on Windows, the GLEW headers use `declspec(dllimport)` for all of the external functions, which mangles all of their names.  This is why all of the missing external symbol names all have `_imp____` at the front.

If you wan't to use a static build of GLEW (you mentioned something about `libglew.a`), define `GLEW_STATIC` during the build of GLEW and during the build of your application.  This will unmangle the names for static linking.

If you want to link to a shared library version of GLEW, make sure to build GLEW with `GLEW_BUILD`.  I'm not sure if this is necessary with gcc but it is if the library is built with MSVC.

Furthermore, the GNU toolchain actually supports Microsoft's `.lib` format for linking.  [source](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use)

You may find it easiest to just compile GLEW yourself or even include it in your project.  It is only one source file and a few headers.  To compile the library manually, use something along the lines of `gcc -shared -o libGLEW.dll -Wl,--out-implib=libGLEW.dll.a -O2 -DGLEW_BUILD glew.c`.  To get the static version use something like `gcc -c -O2 -DGLEW_STATIC glew.c` instead.