# Why would i be getting 4 instances of "undefined reference to `gluErrorString@4'"

Tags: opengl, mingw, codeblocks, undefined-reference, glew

heres my code. an opengl4.0 tutorial:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#define WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX "Chapter 2"

int CurrentWidth = 800,
    CurrentHeight = 600,
    WindowHandle = 0;

unsigned FrameCount = 0;
GLuint
    VertexShaderId,
    FragmentShaderId,
    ProgramId,
    VaoId,
    VboId,
    ColorBufferId;

const GLchar* VertexShader =
{
    "#version 400\n"\
    "layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Position;\n"\
    "layout(location=1) in vec4 in_Color;\n"\
    "out vec4 ex_Color;\n"\

    "void main(void)\n"\
    "{\n"\
    "   gl_Position = in_Position;\n"\
    "   ex_Color = in_Color;\n"\
    "}\n"
};

const GLchar* FragmentShader =
{
    "#version 400\n"\

    "in vec4 ex_Color;\n"\
    "out vec4 out_Color;\n"\

    "void main(void)\n"\
    "{\n"\
    "   out_Color = ex_Color;\n"\
    "}\n"
};

void Initialize(int, char*[]);
void InitWindow(int argc, char* argv[]);
void ResizeFunction(int, int);
void RenderFunction(void);
void TimerFunction(int);
void IdleFunction(void);
void Cleanup(void);
void CreateVBO(void);
void DestroyVBO(void);
void CreateShaders(void);
void DestroyShaders(void);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Initialize(argc, argv);

    glutMainLoop();

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void Initialize(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    GLenum GlewInitResult;
    InitWindow(argc, argv);



    GlewInitResult = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != GlewInitResult) {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: %s\n",
            glewGetErrorString(GlewInitResult)
        );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fprintf(
        stdout,
        "INFO: OpenGL Version: %s\n",
        glGetString(GL_VERSION)
    );

    CreateShaders();
    CreateVBO();
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

void InitWindow(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitContextVersion(4, 0);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

    glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS);

    glutInitWindowSize(CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

    WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX);

    if(WindowHandle < 1) {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: Could not create a new rendering window.\n"
        );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glutReshapeFunc(ResizeFunction);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderFunction);
    glutIdleFunc(IdleFunction);
    glutTimerFunc(0, TimerFunction, 0);
    glutCloseFunc(Cleanup);

}

void ResizeFunction(int Width, int Height)
{
    CurrentWidth = Width;
    CurrentHeight = Height;
    glViewport(0, 0, CurrentWidth, CurrentHeight);
}

void RenderFunction(void)
{
    ++FrameCount;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void IdleFunction(void)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void TimerFunction(int Value)
{
    if (0 != Value) {
        char* TempString = (char*)
            malloc(512 + strlen(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX));

        sprintf(
            TempString,
            "%s: %d Frames Per Second @ %d x %d",
            WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX,
            FrameCount * 10,
            CurrentWidth,
            CurrentHeight
        );

        glutSetWindowTitle(TempString);
        free(TempString);
    }

    FrameCount = 0;
    glutTimerFunc(100, TimerFunction, 1);
}

void Cleanup(void)
{
    DestroyShaders();
    DestroyVBO();
}

void CreateVBO(void)
{
    GLfloat Vertices[] = {
        -0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.0f,  0.8f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    GLfloat Colors[] = {
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VaoId);
    glBindVertexArray(VaoId);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VboId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &ColorBufferId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ColorBufferId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Colors), Colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

    if (ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: Could not create a VBO: %s \n",
            gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue)
        );

        exit(-1);
    }
 }

 void DestroyVBO(void)
{
    GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ColorBufferId);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VboId);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VaoId);

    ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
    if (ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: Could not destroy the VBO: %s \n",
            gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue)
        );

        exit(-1);
    }
}

void CreateShaders(void)
{
    GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

    VertexShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderId, 1, &VertexShader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderId);

    FragmentShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderId, 1, &FragmentShader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderId);

    ProgramId = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(ProgramId, VertexShaderId);
        glAttachShader(ProgramId, FragmentShaderId);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramId);
    glUseProgram(ProgramId);

    ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
    if (ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: Could not create the shaders: %s \n",
            gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue)
        );

        exit(-1);
    }
}

void DestroyShaders(void)
{
    GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

    glUseProgram(0);

    glDetachShader(ProgramId, VertexShaderId);
    glDetachShader(ProgramId, FragmentShaderId);

    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderId);
    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderId);

    glDeleteProgram(ProgramId);

    ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
    if (ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr,
            "ERROR: Could not destroy the shaders: %s \n",
            gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue)
        );

        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

its the full code to what i have in code blocks using mingw that is running on windows 7 x64. its chapter 2 of openglbook.com. its supposed to implement im implementing glew32s, freeglut and opengl in the project link settings (not compiler) and in that order.

i hear running dynamically is better but i get a bunch of undefined glew command errors if i go dynamic. so i had to setup the "#define glew_static" with glew32s in the linker.

what could be causing this?

```
-------------- Build: Debug in 40 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall  -g    -ID:\backup\funstuff\programming\freeglut\include  -c D:\backup\funstuff\programming\40\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\40.exe obj\Debug\main.o    -lglew32s -lfreeglut -lopengl32 
Warning: .drectve `/DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecognized
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `Z9CreateVBOv':
D:/backup/funstuff/programming/40/main.cpp:219: undefined reference to `gluErrorString@4'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `Z10DestroyVBOv':
D:/backup/funstuff/programming/40/main.cpp:247: undefined reference to `gluErrorString@4'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `Z13CreateShadersv':
D:/backup/funstuff/programming/40/main.cpp:278: undefined reference to `gluErrorString@4'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `Z14DestroyShadersv':
D:/backup/funstuff/programming/40/main.cpp:305: undefined reference to `gluErrorString@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
4 errors, 1 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
```

**edit********

I've downloaded wsys and installed mingw to a seperate directory and recompiled glew-1.9.0 and replaced the dll and libs. Still the same error, however without the ~~~~~~~~~~~>Warning: .drectve `/DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecognized<~~~~~~~ warning.

Which btw, was only present because the compiled DLL and libs from glews website were done on VisualC.

Comment: While linking glew32s.lib it must be at the top of the list in codeblocks.

Comment: Possible duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923876/getting-glew-to-compile-in-codeblocks/16930933#16930933

Comment: glew32s and glew32 have always been at the top of my list. I know the issue you're referring to. This is not related. Thank you though!

Comment: If `glew32` is at the top of your list along with `glew32s` then why is only `glew32s` in the list of libraries being passed to the linker?  Your build log only shows these libraries: `-lglew32s -lfreeglut -lopengl32 `

Comment: I didnt want to post 4 different build logs stating with 1, the other or both. I have tried with the 3 variations. And with glew32s before and after glew32.

Comment: Apparently I had to add glu32 after glew32. I thought freeglut or glew headers would have added that. but guess not!... thats at least what stopped the undefined references to gluerrorstring. Now I just need to figure out where my invalid operation is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gluErrorString is defined in glu.h and is located in the glu32.dll. glu32.dll was not added to the linker settings, therefore my code didnt fully recognize these lines.