# How to build my first OpenGL program

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks, sfml, glew

I am having trouble making a simple OpenGL program.
I did some research and found to make OpenGL programs I'll need

- SFML - For creating window
- GLEW - For extension handling

I have been using SFML for a while, it works fine. Following the official SFML page, and adding an additional linker option: **-l opengl32** I managed to compile the typical OpenGL-with-SFML code shown [Here.](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/window-opengl.php)

So i moved on to make OpenGL applications, but i couldn't compile any of the tutorials on the net, due to undefinied references even after setting up GLEW. Now i have [this piece of code](https://open.gl/content/code/c2_color_triangle.txt) taken from the least appreciated answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923876/getting-glew-to-compile-in-codeblocks). I have followed the instructions from that post, but still getting errors:

*C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c|| undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'*

I am using

- Windows 10
- Codeblocks 16.1
- Default MinGW packed with codeblocks
- (SFML, GLEW)

****Edit:****

My full Build log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in opengl_minus1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\prog\SFML\2.3.2\lib -LC:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib -o bin\Debug\opengl_minus1.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -l opengl32  C:\prog\SFML\2.3.2\lib\libsfml-graphics.a C:\prog\SFML\2.3.2\lib\libsfml-window.a C:\prog\SFML\2.3.2\lib\libsfml-system.a C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x29c): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x2b8): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x2e8): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x2fc): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x310): more undefined references to `wglGetProcAddress@4' follow
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x1786c): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x178bf): undefined reference to `wglGetCurrentDC@0'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x1792f): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x17943): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x1795e): undefined reference to `wglGetCurrentDC@0'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x179da): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x17b60): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x17b7c): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x17b9a): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x17f7c): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x17f98): more undefined references to `wglGetProcAddress@4' follow
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x19def): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x19f40): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x19f85): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x19fa1): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x19fbd): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x19fd6): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x1a08f): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj):glew.c:(.text+0x1a0ab): more undefined references to `wglGetProcAddress@4' follow
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\prog\GLEW\1.13\lib\libglew32.a(glew.obj): bad reloc address 0x13a98 in section `.rdata'
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
26 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: Do you link to `opengl32`?

Comment: Somebody suggested me **-l opengl32** I believe it does the job.

Comment: To get help with a failing linkage you need to post, at least,
the failing linkage command and the errors that follow from it,
verbatim from the build output. Add this information in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress` occurs in member `glew.obj` of library `libglew32`
The function `wglGetProcAddress` is defined in `libopengl32` but is not linked because the
linkage order of the libraries is the wrong way round.

In the linkage sequence, files that need symbol definitions must occur before the ones the provide the definitions,
because the linker will only link an object module from a library if it provides
a definition of at least one symbol that is already referenced in the linkage, but not yet defined.

So link `-lopengl32` after `libglew32.a`