# undefined reference to '_imp___glewGenBuffers'

Tags: opengl, codeblocks, glew

I am having the following link errors regarding glew library when compiling an opengl 2.1 program on code blocks,mingw.

```
obj\Debug\LUtil.o||In function `Z6renderv':|
C:\Users\war\Desktop\CG\Hello\LUtil.cpp|162|undefined reference to `_imp____glewGenBuffers'|
C:\Users\war\Desktop\CG\Hello\LUtil.cpp|163|undefined reference to `_imp____glewBindBuffer'|
C:\Users\war\Desktop\CG\Hello\LUtil.cpp|164|undefined reference to `_imp____glewBufferData'|
```

Also, I have properly linked these libraries.
**-lopengl32
-glu32
-glew32
-lfreeglut**

Also, I have make the project find the appropriate header files and libraries.

What else is left?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use GLEW with MinGW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870793/how-to-use-glew-with-mingw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link the library glew32s.lib also. Put this linker at the top of linker list.

Answer (score 3):

This can be caused by attempting to use an MSVC lib under mingw. Either download a library compiled for mingw, or compile your own.